# Need a design for high volume application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture

We are starting a new product at our company and we are expecting a huge volume of saves to be happening on the DB. The db may not be efficient in handling so many saves per second. What would be a good architecture in this case?

We are planning to use spring MVC to interface the client. Use EJBs for saving the data into the DB(spring ejb integration). Obviously Cluster setup but depending on he new architecture.

All the saves that we do needs to be properly transacted. I've never worked with MQs I don't know if it has any advantage over this scenario.

The number of saves to the db will be around 100,000 per (1-5) seconds and its just an estimate. what type of setup would yield better results?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using Apache Kafka to queue your writes and have a consumer application that reads from the queue and writes do the DB. This will reduce the latency on the web server being responsible for synchronously writing to the DB. In several different benchmarking tests, Kafka has been shown to handle up to 500k writes per second. So you'll have plenty of bandwidth to handle the volume you're expecting. Kafka has a java api, so it fits well with your current architecture.